# Плавная анимация цвета при прокрутке

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Здравствуйте!

Задача состоит в том, что бы при прокрутке страницы плавно менялся цвет фона.
Пояснение: 
Есть два цвета ( к примеру `rgb(0, 0, 0)` и `rgb(255, 255, 255)` ). Я в коде указываю позиции scroll'а `0px` и `100px`. И теперь, нужно, что бы скрипт, по мере прокрутки, плавно превращал `rgb(0, 0, 0)` в `rgb(255, 255, 255)`, т.е. если я прокрутил scroll на позицию `50px` цвет у фона был `rgb(122, 122, 122)`.

Я попытался это решить способом процентов, но это же будет работать только с цветами rgb, а как же hex и другие? И вообще оно странно меняет цвета, если там указаны цветные варианты (красный, жёлтый, синий...)

Код:

```js
var scroll = function(element, style, positions, value) {
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset,
        // Высчитываю процент того, на сколько нужно изменить цвет
        pct = (window.pageYOffset - positions[0]) / positions[1],
        colorsVal = [],
        currentColor = [];
    // Проверяю, не выходит ли scroll за рамки
    if(window.pageYOffset <= positions[1] && window.pageYOffset >= positions[0]){
      // Превращаю значение цветов в массив
      colorsVal[0] = value[0].split(',');
      colorsVal[1] = value[1].split(',');
      for(var i = 0; i < colorsVal[0].length; i++){
        // Проверяю, какое значение цвета больше
        if(colorsVal[0][i] < colorsVal[1][i]){
          // Высчитываю текущее значение цвета
          var val = ((colorsVal[1][i] - colorsVal[0][i]) * pct) + colorsVal[0][i];
          // Устанавливаю текущее значение цвета
          currentColor[i] = Math.round(val);
        }else{
          // Высчитываю текущее значение цвета
          var val = ((colorsVal[0][i] - colorsVal[1][i]) * pct) + colorsVal[1][i];
          // Устанавливаю текущее значение цвета
          currentColor[i] = Math.round(val);
        };
      };
      // Применяю цвет фона к элементу
      element.style[style] = 'rgb(' + currentColor.join(',') + ')';
    };
  };
};

(function() {
  var obj = document.querySelector('.obj');
  scroll(obj, 'background-color', [0, 100], ['0,0,0', '255,255,255']);
})();
```

```css
body {height: 2000px; background-color: #eee}
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="obj"></div>
```

Как можно улучшить эту функцию и сделать более универсальной, что бы можно было указывать значение цвета 'black' и hex цвета? Или у кого есть вариант получше моего?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Тоже заинтересовало как плавно меняют цвет от одного к другому.

Comment: @DimenSi, примерно так же, как и я указал. Все примеры, которые нашёл, работают по такому же принципу

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Первое, что необходимо сделать — это убрать для удобства цвет из CSS и задавать его уже непосредственно в функции `scroll` при её инициализации.

Далее я вызвал функцию `scroll` с параметром `positions` `[0, 1000]`, чтобы можно было нормально рассмотреть переход и у меня возникала проблема при каждом втором скролле. Проблема была в том, что массив `colorsVal` заполнялся не числами, а строками, и там, где происходит вычисление `val = ((colorsVal[1][i] - colorsVal[0][i]) * pct) +`**`colorsVal[0][i]`** (проблемное место выделено жирным) ноль прибавляется как строка и получается зашкаливающее значение в `rgb`. Решением является приведение к типу `Number` во время формирования массива:

```
colorsVal[0] = value[0].split(',').map(Number),
colorsVal[1] = value[1].split(',').map(Number);
```

После этого пример от меньших значений `rgb` к большим работает. Дальше возникли проблемы с переходом от больших значений к меньшим. Для решения этой проблемы пришлось немного изменить формулу расчета с

```
val = ((colorsVal[0][i] - colorsVal[1][i]) * pct) + colorsVal[1][i];
```

на

```
val = colorsVal[0][i] - ((colorsVal[0][i] - colorsVal[1][i]) * pct);
```

```js
var scroll = function(element, style, positions, value) {
  // Превращаю значение цветов в массив
  var colorsVal = [], val;
  
  colorsVal[0] = value[0].split(',').map(Number),
  colorsVal[1] = value[1].split(',').map(Number);
  
  element.style[style] = 'rgb(' + colorsVal[0].join(',') + ')';
    
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset,
        // Высчитываю процент того, на сколько нужно изменить цвет
        pct = (window.pageYOffset - positions[0]) / positions[1],
        currentColor = [];
    
    // Проверяю, не выходит ли scroll за рамки
    if(window.pageYOffset <= positions[1] && window.pageYOffset >= positions[0]){
      for(var i = 0; i < colorsVal[0].length; i++) {
        // Проверяю, какое значение цвета больше
        if(colorsVal[0][i] < colorsVal[1][i]){
          // Высчитываю текущее значение цвета
          val = ((colorsVal[1][i] - colorsVal[0][i]) * pct) + colorsVal[0][i];
          // Устанавливаю текущее значение цвета
          currentColor[i] = Math.round(val);
        }else{
          // Высчитываю текущее значение цвета
          val = colorsVal[0][i] - ((colorsVal[0][i] - colorsVal[1][i]) * pct);
          // Устанавливаю текущее значение цвета
          currentColor[i] = Math.round(val);
        };
      };
      // Применяю цвет фона к элементу
      element.style[style] = 'rgb(' + currentColor.join(',') + ')';
    };
  };
};

(function() {
  var obj = document.querySelector('.obj');
  scroll(obj, 'background-color', [0, 1000], ['0,0,0', '255,255,255']);
})();
```

```css
body {height: 2000px; background-color: #eee}
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="obj"></div>
```

```js
console.clear();

var scroll = function(element, style, positions, value) {
  // Превращаю значение цветов в массив
  var colorsVal = [], val;
  
  colorsVal[0] = value[0].split(',').map(Number),
  colorsVal[1] = value[1].split(',').map(Number);
  
  element.style[style] = 'rgb(' + colorsVal[0].join(',') + ')';
    
  window.onscroll = function() {
    var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset,
        // Высчитываю процент того, на сколько нужно изменить цвет
        pct = (window.pageYOffset - positions[0]) / positions[1],
        currentColor = [];
    
    // Проверяю, не выходит ли scroll за рамки
    if(window.pageYOffset <= positions[1] && window.pageYOffset >= positions[0]){
      for(var i = 0; i < colorsVal[0].length; i++) {
        // Проверяю, какое значение цвета больше
        if(colorsVal[0][i] < colorsVal[1][i]){
          // Высчитываю текущее значение цвета
          val = ((colorsVal[1][i] - colorsVal[0][i]) * pct) + colorsVal[0][i];
          // Устанавливаю текущее значение цвета
          currentColor[i] = Math.round(val);
        }else{
          // Высчитываю текущее значение цвета
          val = colorsVal[0][i] - ((colorsVal[0][i] - colorsVal[1][i]) * pct);
          // Устанавливаю текущее значение цвета
          currentColor[i] = Math.round(val);
        };
      };
      // Применяю цвет фона к элементу
      element.style[style] = 'rgb(' + currentColor.join(',') + ')';
    };
  };
};

(function() {
  var obj = document.querySelector('.obj');
  scroll(obj, 'background-color', [0, 1000], ['0,245,0', '255,0,0']);
})();
```

```css
body {height: 2000px; background-color: #eee}
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="obj"></div>
```

Comment: Вообще красавчик =)

Answer (score 3):

Можешь тот же hex конвертировать в rgb.

```js
var hex = document.querySelector('input'),
    btn = document.querySelector('button'),
    rgbBlock = document.querySelector('.rgb'),
    hexval;

btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  hexval = hex.value;
  rgbBlock.innerHTML = hexToRgbA(hexval);
});

function hexToRgbA(hex) {
  var c;
  if (/^#([A-Fa-f0-9]{3}){1,2}$/.test(hex)) {
    c = hex.substring(1).split('');
    if (c.length == 3) {
      c = [c[0], c[0], c[1], c[1], c[2], c[2]];
    }
    c = '0x' + c.join('');
    return 'rgba(' + [(c >> 16) & 255, (c >> 8) & 255, c & 255] + ')';
  }
  
  throw new Error('не Hex');
}
```

```html
<input type="text" />
<button>convert</button>

<div class="rgb"></div>
```